# select/filter rows with R: identify values with the same variable or attribute a code to different consecutive cycles

Tags: r

I am beginner with R and now I am struggling with a new problem.

I have many data.frame structured like the example below.
Every data frame is a long consecutive repetition (approx. 80000 rows per file) of measurements taken from different ports (in the example, only from port 1 to 5). Every cycle from port 1 to 5 is repeated multiple times.

I would like to find the way to filter only the last 3 values of every port in each repeated cycle, and later to calculate the mean between the 3 values.

My problem is how to tell R that every cycle is kind of independent. I tried to `dplyr::filter` each port but I don’t know how to explain R that I have consecutive cycles. I hope it is possible.

Otherwise I thought to find a way to identify each consecutive cycle, so later I could work on the data in according to the number of cycle. Would it be possible?

Thank you

```
date        time            julian_day  port    nh3
28.01.2019  09:44:52.657    28.44783    1   361.9  
28.01.2019  09:44:54.206    28.44785    1   358.6  
28.01.2019  09:44:56.012    28.44787    1   363.6  
28.01.2019  09:44:57.836    28.44789    1   368.8  
28.01.2019  09:44:59.637    28.44791    1   371.8  
28.01.2019  09:45:01.427    28.44793    2   374.8  
28.01.2019  09:45:03.226    28.44795    2   378.4  
28.01.2019  09:45:05.026    28.44797    2   381.8  
28.01.2019  09:45:06.828    28.44800    2   386.3  
28.01.2019  09:45:08.637    28.44802    2   390.3  
28.01.2019  09:45:10.457    28.44804    2   396.3  
28.01.2019  09:45:12.269    28.44806    2   399.1  
28.01.2019  09:45:13.917    28.44808    3   399.1  
28.01.2019  09:45:15.483    28.44810    3   399.2  
28.01.2019  09:45:17.315    28.44812    3   398.1  
28.01.2019  09:45:19.125    28.44814    3   397.5  
28.01.2019  09:45:20.934    28.44816    3   396.1  
28.01.2019  09:45:22.755    28.44818    4   394.9  
28.01.2019  09:45:24.563    28.44820    4   390.6  
28.01.2019  09:45:26.378    28.44822    4   387.1  
28.01.2019  09:45:28.193    28.44824    4   384.9  
28.01.2019  09:45:30.013    28.44826    4   382.7  
28.01.2019  09:45:31.812    28.44828    5   381.8  
28.01.2019  09:45:33.615    28.44831    5   380.6  
28.01.2019  09:45:35.276    28.44832    5   380.6  
28.01.2019  09:45:36.834    28.44834    5   382.2  
28.01.2019  09:45:38.647    28.44836    5   385.5  
28.01.2019  09:45:40.456    28.44838    5   387.3  
28.01.2019  09:45:42.266    28.44841    1   386.3  
28.01.2019  09:45:44.065    28.44843    1   384.6  
28.01.2019  09:45:45.875    28.44845    1   382.4  
28.01.2019  09:45:47.703    28.44847    2   381.1  
28.01.2019  09:45:49.516    28.44849    2   380.5  
28.01.2019  09:45:53.167    28.44853    2   375.2  
28.01.2019  09:45:54.973    28.44855    2   370.8  
28.01.2019  09:45:56.615    28.44857    2   370.8  
28.01.2019  09:45:58.157    28.44859    3   413.1  
28.01.2019  09:45:59.956    28.44861    3   439.2  
28.01.2019  09:46:01.755    28.44863    3   470.7  
28.01.2019  09:46:03.585    28.44865    3   473.6  
28.01.2019  09:46:05.408    28.44867    4   482.6  
28.01.2019  09:46:07.232    28.44869    4   483.1  
28.01.2019  09:46:09.055    28.44872    4   506.1  
28.01.2019  09:46:10.869    28.44874    4   504.6  
28.01.2019  09:46:12.693    28.44876    4   504.8  
28.01.2019  09:46:14.510    28.44878    5   508.7  
28.01.2019  09:46:16.332    28.44880    5   508.5  
28.01.2019  09:46:18.006    28.44882    5   508.5  
28.01.2019  09:46:19.581    28.44884    5   503.9  
28.01.2019  09:46:21.395    28.44886    5   502.4  
28.01.2019  09:46:23.214    28.44888    5   494.9
```

## assigning to each cycle a consecutive value, the table would appear like this:

```
date        time            julian_day  port    nh3   cycle    
28.01.2019  09:44:52.657    28.44783    1   361.9 1   
28.01.2019  09:44:54.206    28.44785    1   358.6 1   
28.01.2019  09:44:56.012    28.44787    1   363.6 1  
28.01.2019  09:44:57.836    28.44789    1   368.8  1  
28.01.2019  09:44:59.637    28.44791    1   371.8  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:01.427    28.44793    2   374.8  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:03.226    28.44795    2   378.4  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:05.026    28.44797    2   381.8  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:06.828    28.44800    2   386.3  1   
28.01.2019  09:45:08.637    28.44802    2   390.3  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:10.457    28.44804    2   396.3  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:12.269    28.44806    2   399.1  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:13.917    28.44808    3   399.1  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:15.483    28.44810    3   399.2  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:17.315    28.44812    3   398.1  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:19.125    28.44814    3   397.5  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:20.934    28.44816    3   396.1  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:22.755    28.44818    4   394.9  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:24.563    28.44820    4   390.6  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:26.378    28.44822    4   387.1  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:28.193    28.44824    4   384.9  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:30.013    28.44826    4   382.7  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:31.812    28.44828    5   381.8  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:33.615    28.44831    5   380.6  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:35.276    28.44832    5   380.6  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:36.834    28.44834    5   382.2  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:38.647    28.44836    5   385.5  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:40.456    28.44838    5   387.3  1  
28.01.2019  09:45:42.266    28.44841    1   386.3  2  
28.01.2019  09:45:44.065    28.44843    1   384.6  2  
28.01.2019  09:45:45.875    28.44845    1   382.4  2   
28.01.2019  09:45:47.703    28.44847    2   381.1  2  
28.01.2019  09:45:49.516    28.44849    2   380.5  2  
28.01.2019  09:45:53.167    28.44853    2   375.2  2  
28.01.2019  09:45:54.973    28.44855    2   370.8  2  
28.01.2019  09:45:56.615    28.44857    2   370.8  2  
28.01.2019  09:45:58.157    28.44859    3   413.1  2  
28.01.2019  09:45:59.956    28.44861    3   439.2  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:01.755    28.44863    3   470.7  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:03.585    28.44865    3   473.6  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:05.408    28.44867    4   482.6  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:07.232    28.44869    4   483.1  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:09.055    28.44872    4   506.1  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:10.869    28.44874    4   504.6  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:12.693    28.44876    4   504.8  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:14.510    28.44878    5   508.7  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:16.332    28.44880    5   508.5  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:18.006    28.44882    5   508.5  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:19.581    28.44884    5   503.9  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:21.395    28.44886    5   502.4  2  
28.01.2019  09:46:23.214    28.44888    5   494.9  2
```

Comment: Can you please format the examples

Comment: Could you please post the output of `dput(yourdata)` so that we may easily reproduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distinguish between the cycles, we can use `data.table::rleid` to create a run-length type id column divide it by 5 (since we have 5 ports) and wrap it in `ceiling`

```
df$cycle <- ceiling(data.table::rleid(df$port)/5)
```

If we don't want to use packages, we can also use base R, `rle` along the same lines

```
df$cycle <- ceiling(with(rle(df$port), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))/5)
```